# Is there a way to prevent the "bad connection" or "no network" error inside python?

Tags: python, urlopen

I use *urlopen* command from *urllib.request* package and it works properly.

But because it is inside an infinite loop I want to consider the possible "No network" Conditions. I do not want my code to break down because of this error.

I tried the function below but it does not work:

```py
def update():
    try:
        cmd = 'getUpdates'
        resp = urlopen(URL + cmd)
        line = aux_dec2utf8(resp)
        upds = json.loads(line)
        NoM = len(upds['result'])
    except ValueError:
        print('NO NETWORK')    
    return NoM, upds
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAk87.png)

Comment: Did you mean: `except UrlError:`?

Comment: I didn't get it

Comment: What didn't you get?

Comment: do you mean to change "except ValueError:" with "except UrlError:" ?

Comment: Thankyou it is solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue here is the ValueError exception.  You may want to set up an exception for urllib.HTTPError and/or urllib.URLError to catch the error you’re attempting to keep from breaking your script.

ValueError is used to catch an invalid argument and may not be what’s killing the flow.